# Publishing Web App and DB to Azure - The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I'm migrating my application from local to Azure and encountering the following error:

> The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since
>   the database was created.

My database consists of ASP.net Identity fields and some other tables that I've added:
[image]

Initial Migration:

```
namespace WebApplication12.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class init : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetRoles",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .Index(t => t.Name, unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex");

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetUserRoles",
                c => new
                    {
                        UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        RoleId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId })
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetRoles", t => t.RoleId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.UserId)
                .Index(t => t.RoleId);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetUsers",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                        EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        PasswordHash = c.String(),
                        SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                        PhoneNumber = c.String(),
                        PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
                        LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                        AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .Index(t => t.UserName, unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetUserClaims",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        ClaimType = c.String(),
                        ClaimValue = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.UserId);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetUserLogins",
                c => new
                    {
                        LoginProvider = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        ProviderKey = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.LoginProvider, t.ProviderKey, t.UserId })
                .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.UserId);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserLogins", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserClaims", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "RoleId", "dbo.AspNetRoles");
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserLogins", new[] { "UserId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserClaims", new[] { "UserId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "UserNameIndex");
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", new[] { "RoleId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", new[] { "UserId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.AspNetRoles", "RoleNameIndex");
            DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserLogins");
            DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserClaims");
            DropTable("dbo.AspNetUsers");
            DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserRoles");
            DropTable("dbo.AspNetRoles");
        }
    }
}
```

Latest migration:

```
namespace WebApplication12.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class paymentsmodel : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I have researched this throughout StackOverflow and am still completely lost. When I look at the migrations, the initial one includes all of the ASP.net Identity tables, but none of the additional tables I add. When I run another migration, it's empty.

Comment: Please read on the following articles:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/04/08/ef-code-first-migrations-deployment-to-an-azure-cloud-service/

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/04/08/ef-code-first-migrations-deployment-to-an-azure-cloud-service/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but none of the additional tables I add.  When I run another migration, it's empty.

Make sure that you do not change any model in your tables. If you have change model, you need to use `add-migration` command and `update-database` to [update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

And click "**Execute Code First Migrations(runs on application start)**" in settings when you publish your website,which could update your changes to azure.

[image]

Also, you could **delete the record** created in the **_MigrationHistory table** from SQL Server Object Explorer in your local.

Adding the following line in `Application_Start()` in **Global.asax** :

```
Database.SetInitializer<Models.YourDbContext>(null);
```